# How do I run a .war file as a windows service?

Tags: windows, java

How do I run a .war file as a windows service?
I am wanting to install `logsniffer` and the download is a `.war` file.
You run it through a command prompt..however when the user is logged off or the server is restarted, I'm assuming this will no longer be working.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You are correct, that if you, as a logged-in user in a GUI session, run a Java program from a commandline, that program will end when you log off.

.war files are Java. So, you need to run a Java program as a Windows service.

You need to either manually create a service from scratch that calls all the command line things you need and handles startup, restart, etc, or use a third-party program to do that. I've used this one, it's pretty good. https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html

There's a bunch of other ones suggested in the answers to this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app

FYI - please read the Help Guidelines here. Putting more effort into your question will go a long way, both in being a good community member here, and your own learning and career path.
https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for that. I've never done anything about Java... could I fork the repo (it doesn't seem to be an active project anyway) and somehow modify it so that I can set it up in tomcat as a native web app?

Comment: I'm sure you could. You'd want to ask a community of developers instead of a community of sysadmins, probably.

Comment: In fact, the first hit in Google for "run java WAR in tomcat" is this Q&A at StackOverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7